# Copy cell value of formula POI

Tags: java, arrays, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to copy cell value of an excel file to another excel file.
However the source file contains formula and when I getting the cell, I am getting the formula and in my final file I get the formula and not the value.

```
for (int j = 0; j < cellSource[0].length; j++)
{ //For each columns of source
    for (int i = 0; i < cellFinal[0].length ; i++)
    { //For each columns of final
        if (cellSource[0][j].toString().equals(cellFinal[0][i].toString()))
         { //Checking is Equals
            for (int p = 0; p < cell.length; p++)
            { //If their are equals, replace the data
                cellFinal[p][i].setCellValue(cellSource[p][j].toString());
                //Replace the value with the Formula of the main
            }
        }
    }                               
}
```

I tried few things as `getCachedFormulaResultType()` but it's not working..

```
Cell cell = rowFileDa.getCell();
switch (cell .getCellType()) {
     case FORMULA:
         fileDa[i][j] = cell.getCachedFormulaResultType().toString();
         break;
         //Return NUMERIC
}
```

Thanks !

Solved it :

```
cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cellSource[p][j]);
String tmp = cellValue.formatAsString();
tmp = tmp.replace("\"", "");

if (isNumeric(tmp) == false) {
     cell[p][i].setCellValue(tmp);
} else {
    double tmpBis = Double.valueOf(tmp);
     cell[p][i].setCellValue(tmpBis);
 }
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Best practice is using `DataFormatter` together with `FormulaEvaluator`: [DataFormatter.formatCellValue(Cell cell, FormulaEvaluator evaluator)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator-)

Comment: Just solved it, code posted in the main. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `cell.toString()`, use cell value.

According to the Cell API: [Apache POI Javadoc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/)

the options are `getBooleanCellValue(), getDateCellValue(), getErrorCellValue(), getNumericCellValue(), getRichStringCellValue(), getStringCellValue()`.

Comment: Edited to clarify